# Add Fragment into a container

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have Navigation Drawer Activity and I want to set in the main activity frame.
In the frame I want to set a fragment.I'm new and I'm not sure how to do that.
And also from into that frame, I want to replace fragments when the user taps on the navigation drawer.

**This is the XML of the main activity**

```
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.world.bolandian.talent.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

</FrameLayout>
```

as you can see I added a frameLayout.

now I want to set the "Home fragment" when the user logs in to the add.
Also when he the user uses the navigation drawer so it will replace the home fragment with other fragments.

My question is how should I do that?

**EDIT**

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    GenresFragment genresFragment = new GenresFragment();

   // getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,new GenresFragment()).commit();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.container, genresFragment);
    transaction.commit();
```

it gives me error in the genres error. my purpose is to set fragment when the user enter to the app. When the onCreate run

Comment: Read up on [Navigation Drawers](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) and how to use [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can add a fragment from the calling activity

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,new HomeFragment()).commit();
```

here is a [link](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) to an example of the navigation bar which also describes the fragment replacing when the user selects different options from the navigation menu

Comment: For some reason it gives me error in the "new HomeFragment()", have any idea why?

Comment: just make sure that HomeFragment() exits and has Fragment as the parent. share your log or extact error .

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace with the container id.

```
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
    transaction.commit();
```

Comment: For some reason it gives me error in the "new HomeFragment()", have any idea why?